# C# run Powershell script async

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script using the following method:

```
>    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(
>                     @"write-output balls;Start-Sleep -s 2;write-output balls;Start-Sleep -s 2;write-output balls;Start-Sleep -s 2");
```

This works fine, however the following does not. Any ideas?

```
   PowerShellInstance.AddScript(
                    @"c:\folder\script.ps1");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is why...

```
PowerShellInstance.AddScript(
                    @"& ""c:\folder\script.ps1""");
```

Comment: Brevity is OK, but further explanation always helps the OP as well as other users of SO as the generic knowledge base.